# How to extract exception error to property?

Tags: c#

How do I extract the exception from the error into the propery `status`?  This doesn't work:

```
public class MyClass{
    public string status { get; set; }

    public string MyAction() {
        try {
            ...
            status = "OK";
            return status;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //throw ex;
            status = ex;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't assign `Exception` to a `string`... Did you mean to do `status = ex.Message`?

Comment: Don't you see...`ex` is a variable of type `Exception`, and `status` is a `string`? `status = ex.ToString();` is what technically does what you're looking for, but I won't say this is a good exception handling design...

Comment: You should catch the specific types of exceptions happening, and create an enumeration for them so you could have properties like ErrorType and ErrorMessage.  With ErrorType.Success being 0 in the enumeration.  Or something like that.  Using a string to drive a status in c# is a really bad design.  Enumerations are much more reliable and easier to work with.  Also, ToString on an enumeration will spit out the values name.  And you can use Enum.Parse to parse a name into it's enumeration value.

Comment: @Ryios what if its a custom response from a `WebException`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? If you can't handle an exception, **don't catch it**.

Comment: Well, just to point out the obvious: "status = ex.ToString();" This has the advantage of formatting the entire exception including stack trace and inner exceptions. But as others have pointed out this is not all that sophisticated a way of handling exceptions.

Comment: By the way, be aware that ex.Message is localized, so it will typically be different for the same exception on PCs in France and Germany.

Comment: @ZeeTee, That depends on the webservice you are calling.  All webservices are written differently error handling wise.  The good ones don't throw errors at all, they wrap them in some kind of error object which is just serialized from some XML and generall contain an error code in all of the responses.

Or are you writing your own web service layer?

Comment: @Ryios No, but the webservice does give it's own error. But from my experience, you always want to capture the error of a webrequest, in case it never reaches the webservice.

Comment: Ok so your talking about your code accessing the web service erroring out because the webservice errored out.  E.g. say it times out, so the .net code on your end generates an exception, which you then catch.

If so, why do you need to store status etc?  Your not building a web service your building a client to use the web service no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're assigning the Exception object to the status variable. You need to use the actual message property of the Exception like so:

```
status = ex.Message;
return status;
```

Comment: So you're saying all I have to do is change the current code in `catch` to what you have and it should all work?

Comment: I did, and it doesn't work. If I change it back to `throw ex;` it works, and returns the error.

Comment: It gives this error on `MyAction()` in the debugger: *not all code paths return a value*

Comment: Because your method isn't returning a value if you're just setting a variable. You should either return `status` after you give it a value, or return a generic error message.

Comment: Well really if all you're doing is returning `status` (bad idea in my opinion) then you don't even need the variable. You can just do `return ex.Message;`.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
  public class MyClass

{
    public string status { get; set; }

    public string MyAction() {
    try {

       return status = "OK";
    }
      catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw ex;
       return status = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Two problems. 1 - Not all exceptions have an inner exception. 2 - This will not return the message of either exception.

Comment: @logarr i just show the demo he can change that to message now is it clear